# How do I select top N rows grouped by an ID in big query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a database of (changed items/data) grocery story aisles and products, and I'm trying to find the top 3 most expensive items in each aisle that are in stock.

My code for big query is this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aisle ORDER BY price DESC) AS high_prices, aisle, 
price, product FROM `a_database.shopping.grocery_stores`
WHERE in_stock = TRUE AND high_prices <= 3
GROUP BY aisle 
ORDER BY price;
```

I am receiving an error of: `unrecognized name: high_prices at [2:30]` due to the `high_prices <= 3`, however, I don't know another approach to this.

I am expecting an output of the 4 most expensive items by aisle in the store that are in stock, as said. but it doesn't work due to above error. When I remove `high_prices <= 3`, instead I'm getting a list of all items in the store along with their aisles completely out of order.

How would I get a result that makes this query viable?

The expected output is similar to this screenshot:

[image]

I have included a sample data table:

```
aisle    product        in_stock    price
1        fresh_chicken  TRUE        10
2        frozen_fish    TRUE        10
3        truffles       TRUE        15
2        cereal         TRUE        5
2        cake           TRUE        25
3        wine           TRUE        30
1        fresh_fish     TRUE        15
1        fresh_beef     TRUE        10
2        seasonings     FALSE       15
3        whiskey        TRUE        25
1        whiskey        TRUE        40
1        pre_cooked     TRUE        30
2        fresh_pie      FALSE       10
3        fresh_salad    FALSE       5
```

Any help or advice with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below

```
select *
from your_table
where in_stock
qualify 3 >= row_number() over(partition by aisle order by price desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: I'm receiving a syntax error from the `>=`, is this due to the query having a join between two tables?

Comment: i don't see any joins/two-tables in your questions and in my answer!!

Comment: I thought I could dissect the question more as it was a logic issue, but it seems to be deeper than a logic issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use HAVING if you want to reference aliases

```
SELECT *  FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY aisle ORDER BY price DESC) AS high_prices, aisle, 
       price, product 
    FROM `a_database.shopping.grocery_stores`
    WHERE in_stock = TRUE
    GROUP BY aisle ) t1 
WHERE high_prices <= 3
ORDER BY price;
```

Comment: Receiving error `Column high_prices contains an analytic function, which is not allowed in a HAVING clause at 4[8]`. So not sure where to go from there.

Comment: yes you are right WINDOW have that limitation, it is because of the nature of it, so you need another query around sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

Use subquery:

```
select *
from (select row_number() over (partition by aisle order by price desc) row_number,
             aisle,
             price,
             product
      from a_database.shopping.grocery_stores
      where in_stock is true) a
where row_number <= 3
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).